# Run NET Core service as "Network Service"

Tags: .net-core, windows-services

I'm getting the error "the service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion" (1053) when trying to start a .NET Core service as "NT Authority\NetworkService" or "NT Authority\LocalService". But it works fine as "NT Authority\System".

This is the full code of the service I'm trying to run (for testing purposes):

```
using System.ServiceProcess;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServiceBase.Run(new ServiceBase());
        }
    }
}
```

And the csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win7-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController" Version="4.7.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

After building the project, I copied the files to another folder with permissions for the service accounts (to prevent getting the error 5: access denied).

Running as System:

```
$ sc create ConsoleApp1 binPath= "c:\Test\ConsoleApp1.exe" obj= "NT Authority\System"
[SC] CreateService ÊXITO

$ sc start ConsoleApp1

NOME_DO_SERVIÇO: ConsoleApp1
    TIPO                       : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS
    ESTADO                     : 2  START_PENDING
                                (NOT_STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
    CÓDIGO_DE_SAÍDA_DO_WIN32   : 0  (0x0)
    CÓDIGO_DE_SAÍDA_DO_SERVIÇO : 0  (0x0)
    PONTO_DE_VERIFICAÇÃO       : 0x0
    AGUARDAR_DICA              : 0x7d0
    PID                        : 11288
    SINALIZADORES              :

$
```

Running as NetworkService:

```
$ sc create ConsoleApp1 binPath= "c:\Test\ConsoleApp1.exe" obj= "NT Authority\NetworkService"
[SC] CreateService ÊXITO

$ sc start ConsoleApp1
[SC] StartService FALHA 1053:

O serviço não respondeu à requisição de início ou controle em tempo hábil.

$
```

> The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion

I was able to make it work as "NetworkService" after adding this account into "Administrators" group, but I would not do that in a production server.

Comment: You should try the Worker Service template, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Running as System would not be a big problem, I just want know why it cant run as Network Service or Local Service. Also I found the same code runs fine as a windows service with NetworkService account if targeting net472, or netcore3.0 or higher. It fails only with netcoreapp2.2 or lower. But I'm stuck with netcoreapp2.2 until the company buy new licenses for vs2019 Pro.

Comment: I think you forgot a few important steps such as NTFS file permissions, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#create-and-manage-the-windows-service Only administrators by default have access to almost everywhere.

Comment: I got error 5 (access denied) if the folder permissions are not set properly. Also, it does not work even as "NT Authority\System" in a Win2016 server.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was happening due to missing referenced assemblies that are not part of the NET Core runtime, I found this by running the executable in the console instead of starting it as a service. Unfortunatelly the Windows service controller is not able to log those errors.

The vs2017 cant publish NET Core console projects using 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk' template, so I switched to 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web' and published, then all required assemblies were copied to the target folder.

The vs2017 already copied those assemblies to bin folder automatically for NET Core 3.1, but not for NET Core 2.2.